# react router v4 match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, match

I took this example from the official docs https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params, but i rly dont get docs that well. So i understand most of the code but i dont understand `<Route path="/:id" component={Child}/>` how does this works (how the hell is it matching all of the `Links`)

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const ParamsExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <h2>Accounts</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/netflix">Netflix</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/zillow-group">Zillow Group</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/yahoo">Yahoo</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/modus-create">Modus Create</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Route path="/:id" component={Child}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Child = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    {match.params.id}
    <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
  </div>
)

export default ParamsExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line reading `<Route path="/:id" component={Child}/>` defines a path of `/:id`. This describes the pattern of a "/" followed by any string (although it'll stop matching if it finds another '/'). When the URL in the browser address bar matches this pattern (e.g. "/modus-create"), it will store the value of the string following the "/" in a parameter called `id` (defined by the `:id` part).

The `<Links to="foo">` get rendered as `<a href="{whatever.their.to.prop.says}">Link text</a>`. These have a click/tap handler attached that update the browser's state history by adding the new href.

The router passes an object to the component associated to the `<Route>`, as a prop called `match`. With this object, the component can inspect what path was matched and which parameters the router pulled out. You can see the results of that with the output from the line that reads `<h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>`